# In sorbet can you use the return type of one object as the typing for the argument of another?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Take the following line of code:

```
csv_text = T.let(File.read(csv_address), String)
@csv = T.let(CSV.parse(csv_text), T.any(CSV::Table,
                                        T::Array[T::Array[T.untyped]]))
```

The typing for `@csv` is clumsy because at the moment it's manually copying the potential return types from `CSV.parse`.

Is there any way to pass the return type of `CSV.parse` as a variable that can be used to declare the type of `@csv`? i.e. something similar to:

```
csv_text = T.let(File.read(csv_address), String)
@csv = T.let(CSV.parse(csv_text), CSV.parse.return_sig)
```

Comment: No there isn't, but I would suggest a mild improvement. `CSV.parse` needs a really broad return type because the type of its specific result depends on the input parameters. In your concrete case, you'll only ever have a `CSV::Table` _or_ a `T::Array[T::Array[T::Untyped]]`. I'd suggest you type `@csv` as one of those concrete types

Comment: And use a `T.cast` to assert it?

Comment: Yep! Curious, if you use a `T.cast`, do you also need a  `T.let`?

Comment: I actually binned typing on this code in the end as it was only needed temporarily and it was adding more overhead than it saved. So I'm afraid I couldn't tell you!